# Java Loop with condition inside

Tags: java, knime

I am not experienced in Java, but I need to create Java snippet node in KNIME.

I am trying to write a short Loop that creates a counter/iterator based on a specific condition. I managed to write the IF THEN ELSE part but I wonder how to put it inside the Loop:

```
out_user_session_counter = 1;

if (c_session_end.equals("session end")) {
    out_user_session_counter = out_user_session_counter + 1; 
} else {
    out_user_session_counter = out_user_session_counter + 0;
}
```

The idea is: each time `c_session_end.equals("session end")`
then `out_user_session_counter` should be augmented by 1

**UPD.:** Here is screenshot of data model with loop result (not correct result):

[image: example screenshot]

Correct expected result would be 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 
instead of  1 1 1 1 11 1 11 1 1 1 1

Comment: Which is the condition of the loop?

Comment: I don't see any loop in the code you show.

Comment: Note the else branch is completely useless (it does nothing)

Comment: @PaoloMossini condition is c_session_end.equals("session end")

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes, I don't understand how to put it to the code ..

Comment: @Milena I mean how many times you want to execute the instruction in the loop?

Comment: @PaoloMossini as many times as many rows there are in the dataset

Comment: @Milena is there a variable with the number of rows in the dataset?

Comment: @PaoloMossini there is default KNIME variable ROWINDEX which keep the row id in the dataset

Comment: @Milena you don't need the row id, you need the total number of rows

Comment: @PaoloMossini let's say it's 10 rows

Comment: @Milena I provide you an answer. Check it and tell me if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the loop counter to persist between rows in the Java Snippet.  To do that, you define it in the `//Your custom variables:` part of the snippet:

```
int sessionCounter=0;
```

Then in the `//Enter you code here:` part:

```
if("session end".equalsIgnoreCase(c_column2)){
    sessionCounter++;
}

out_user_session_counter = sessionCounter;
```

As shown, the row with 'session end' will contain the incremented counter.  If you want it to contain the old counter, change the snippet so that the final line above is before the `if` statement.

You don't need to put this in a loop in KNIME - the expression part of the snippet is already calculated sequentially for each input row.  Shown below in the snippet dialog for clarity

[image]

Comment: This really helped! And the result is as expected!

Answer (score 1):

You need to work with `for`/`while` loops to achieve that.

```
int out_user_session_counter = 1; //Step 1

while(c_session_end.equals("session_end")) { //Step 2
     out_user_session_counter++;  //Step 3
     //Step 4 Other code to modify c_session_end.equals("session_end")
}
```

**Step 1.** In this step we initialize the variable to 1

**Step 2.** While the variable is equal to `session_end`

**Step 3.** increment the variable by 1 ( note that this is the same as out_user_session_counter = out_user_session_counter + 1; )

**Step 4.** Code to modify the `c_session_end` value must be placed so loop exits as some point or the loop will never stop.

What happens in your code is the following => `if(c_session_end.equals("session end"))` increment the variable by one, otherwise increment it with 0.

If you want it to run multiple times you have to use `while` or `for` loops.

Comment: This is a nice little infinite loop, unless some other thread modifies `c_session_end`

Comment: Yes, `c_session_end` never change in the loop, and  `out_user_session_counter `will increase endlessly

Comment: thx @AyoubRossi i tried it but the result is not what I expected [link](https://i.imgur.com/A6kpLun.png)

Comment: What did you use as a condition to stop the while loop?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
out_user_session_counter = 1;
int loopCycles = 10

for(int i = 0; i < loopCycles; i++){
    if (c_session_end.equals("session end")) {
        out_user_session_counter = out_user_session_counter + 1; 
    }
}
```

Comment: As someone else has pointed out, the else branch does nothing.  Also please try to add some explanation to what you are doing, don't just post the code as it won't help them learn anything.

Comment: Here is the result of this loop: [link](https://i.imgur.com/6nzbwLQ.png) It just counts the number of "session end" occurrences. The expected result is:
1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 3

Comment: Is the `out_user_session_counter` an integer?

Answer (score 0):

You need a simple loop and this will take care of your else part itself.

```
int out_user_session_counter = 1;

while(c_session_end.equals("session end")){
  out_user_session_counter++;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is an  infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

Well, we don't know what you are looping, but I assume you are looping some `String`s.
This example shows how to loop a `List<String>` containing session events while counting the ones that equal `"session end"`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create a data structure for sample data
    List<String> sessionEvents = new ArrayList<String>();
    // add some sample data
    sessionEvents.add("session start");
    sessionEvents.add("session somthing");
    sessionEvents.add("session end");
    sessionEvents.add("session start");
    sessionEvents.add("session something");
    sessionEvents.add("session something");
    sessionEvents.add("session something");
    sessionEvents.add("session end");
    sessionEvents.add("session start");
    sessionEvents.add("session something");
    sessionEvents.add("session end");

    // define a counter variable (considering Java naming conventions)
    int outSessionCounter = 0;

    // use an enhanced for loop (aka for-each loop)
    for (String sessionEvent : sessionEvents) {
        // every time the event is "session end"...
        if (sessionEvent.equals("session end")) {
            // ... increment the counter
            outSessionCounter++;
        }
    }

    // print the result
    System.out.println("Amount of session ends is " + outSessionCounter);
}
```

> This just counts occurrences of `"session end"`, but you would have to tell us if you are using a different data structure or maybe even a stream.

Comment: Thx @deHaar I am looping row number, and I need to increase counter by 1 each time c_session_end.equals("session_end"), I don't need to count occurrences of this value. I attach the link to screenshot with data structure:  [link](https://i.imgur.com/A6kpLun.png)

Comment: @Milena OK, could you edit your question and add your loop that goes through the row numbers along with your screenshot?

Comment: @Milena the data structure you linked looks a little like an excel sheet, but I don't think it is one. How do you receive the data from the application shown in that image? Is it a tool that exports a csv file or anything? How do you access the rows and cells?

Comment: yes, the data structure is just a simple table like xls

Comment: @Milena OK, are you using apache poi? You would basically have to loop the rows, access the cell that holds the value and check if it equals `"session end"`. Every time that condition is met, increment the counter.

Answer (score 0):

Im not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve, but I think I have something

```
    class Result{
        public int out_user_session_counter = 1;
        public String c_session_end;
    }
    Result r = new Result();
    r.c_session_end = /*[whatever you want it to be];*/ "";
    Thread thread = (new Thread(new Runnable() {
        int out_user_session_counter = 1;

        public void run() {
            out_user_session_counter = 1;
            while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                if (r.c_session_end.equals("session end")) {
                    out_user_session_counter++;
                    r.out_user_session_counter = out_user_session_counter;
                }
                //code to modify the r.c_session_end
            }
        }
    }));
    thread.start();
    //to get the result do
    int result = r.out_user_session_counter;
```

this will keep looping indefinitely.(this can go within a method)
you can edit the result object to influence the

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do something like:

```
    out_user_session_counter = 1;
    int loop_counter =0;
    int rows = 10 //or some other variable that contains the number of rows 
    while(loop_counter < rows) {
       if (c_session_end.equals("session end")) {
          out_user_session_counter = out_user_session_counter++; 
          loop_counter++; 
       }
       System.out.println(out_user_session_counter); 
    }
```

All you need to do is add a loop to the outer portion of you code. Any loop will do, I used a `while` loop. You could use a for loop as well.

```
for(int i = 0; ii < rows; ii++){
   if (c_session_end.equals("session end")) {
      out_user_session_counter = out_user_session_counter++; 
   }
   System.out.println(out_user_session_counter);   
}
```

Or, you can use a `do-while` loop:

```
int index = 0; 
do{
   if (c_session_end.equals("session end")) {
      out_user_session_counter = out_user_session_counter++; 
      index++; 
   }
   System.out.println(out_user_session_counter); 
} while (index < rows);
```

It should be noted that with the `do-while` loop, you will alway enter the loop, even if there are no rows available (the rows are 0).

Also, you don't need the else portion, as there is no point in adding 0 to your value, you can simply skip it.

Comment: I used this code:

int rows = 11;
int out_user_session_counter = 1;

for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
   if (c_session_end.equals("session end")) {
      out_user_session_counter = out_user_session_counter++; 
   }
}

But the result was empty values

Comment: What was empty? If you are trying to print out the values, you need to add a `System.out.println(out_user_session_counter);` after the `if` statement. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: no, in KNIME they are printed out automatically, you don't need a special command

Comment: it works now and returns values, but the result is not what expected.
it just counts the numbers of rows, and doesn't work as iterator: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHWu2.png)

Comment: Are you initializing the ` out_user_session_counter` outside of the loop?